# Browserify + angular-fullpage.js

Tags: angularjs, browserify, fullpage.js

I have an application that relies on Browserify. I am trying to add  the [angular-fullpage.js](https://github.com/hellsan631/angular-fullpage.js) module to my application but am having trouble. This is what my Package.JSON looks like:

```
"browser": {
    "fullpage": "./node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/fullpage.min.js",
    "angular-fullpage.js": "./node_modules/angular-fullpage.js/angular-fullpage.min.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "fullpage.js": {
      "exports": "fullpage",
      "depends": "jquery"
    },
    "angular-fullpage.js": {
      "exports": "angular.module('fullPage.js').name",
      "depends": "fullpage.js"
    }
}
```

I require the module in the AngularJS application using

```
require('angular-fullpage.js')
```

When I run the application, I get:

```
Failed to instantiate module portal due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Now fullpage.js version 3 (no jQuery required) is now available for Angular in the official repository:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage

Hope that helps!